# RGraph: how to change background color?

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I have a web page with 3 rgraph dynamically updated Line charts.
I use ajax call for retrieving data from web service.
When ajax call completed with error I want to change the chart background color to 'gray'. And when call is successful to change this color to 'black'.

How to change chart background color dynamically?

I use this code

```
if(error_occured)
 obj_Memory.Set('background.color', '#B6B6B4');
else
 obj_Memory.Set('background.color', 'black');
```

But it does not change the color.

I modified rgraph sample:

http://www.rgraph.net/demos/line-dynamic-updates.html

Added button and simple function:

```
    var error_occured = false;

    document.getElementById("toggleButton1").onclick = function (e) {
        if (error_occured)
            obj.Set('background.color', '#B6B6B4');
        else
            obj.Set('background.color', 'black');
        RG.redraw();
        error_occured = !error_occured;
    }
```

It does not change the chart background

There is modified file from RGraph examples.
It must be copied to \demo folder.

http://rghost.net/6qZm2jCBS

What interesting:  the call of

obj.Set('background.color', 'gray');

inside of drawGraph - works fine(!)
But outside does not work.

Comment: Try changing this: RG.redraw(); to this: RGraph.redraw(); If that fails check the JavaScript console for an error message. And post a link to an example page.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded RGraph, then modified sample file (see the initial post) and do experiment. I simply added button and function (see above too). I tried RG.redraw() and RGraph.redraw(). It does not work. There are no error messages in console. What I do wrong?

Comment: No idea. You'll need to put the file online so that I can see it.

Comment: 1. Download RGraph here: 
http://www.rgraph.net/download
and unzip it.
2. Download my file here:
http://rghost.net/6qZm2jCBS
3. Copy my file to RGraph install folder \demo

Comment: Your rghost URL results in a network error

Comment: I checked it works. But try this http://www37.zippyshare.com/v/mA0vNJgu/file.html\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69829/discussion-between-richard-and-oleg).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
RGraph.redraw();
```

After the Set() call.

Comment: Please check my 1st post. I added description.